# why I am getting java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle.getFillBackgroundColorColor()?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am getting this error in Java in the below line:

```
Color cellColor = (row.getCell(1).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor());`
```

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle.getFillBackgroundColorColor()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Color;

I have also checked the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and there are only two Jars `ojdbc5.jar` and `ojdbc6.jar`

I don't know why I am getting this error while using `getFillBackgroundColorColor()`.

Basically, I want to get the color of a cell. Can someone help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

An AbstractMethodError usually means that there is a mixup in dependencies. Perhaps you are missing poi-ooxml or have multiple versions of it?

Answer (score 2):

Having `WEB-INF/lib` implies that you are deploying a WAR file. In this case libraries can be in few different places e.g. `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`. Check your classpath e.g. by printing all the URLs that are part of it:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
for (URL url : urls) {
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}
```

and make sure that POI is in the right version. If you are using Tomcat you can check out [this article](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath).

As a side note your probably shouldn't ship `ojdbc5.jar`, it's a very old driver for a very old JDK and Oracle DB.

Comment: I have updated the POI jars and the error has gone now, but I want to get the color name (like Green, Yellow) but with current code its returning object `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@dd523353`. can you help me to get the color name ?

Comment: XSSFColor contains a RGB value which you can get by invoking getTGB() method. There are in total 16,777,216 unique RGB values, so there is really no way to get the colour name for each of them. If you have a set of common RGB values that you need you need to label, I would suggest creating a map that would translate the RGB to a corresponding colour name.

Comment: Ok Thanks. will try this way.